# How can I populate ArrayAdapter with objects?

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I have a POJO like this:

```
public class Color {
 private int id;
 private int name;
 //getter setter
}
```

In my AsyncTask I call the server and get bunch of these objects and then want to populate my list. I do this by:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        colorsList = MyManager.INSTANCE.getService().getColors();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Color>(MyActivity.this,R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.name, colorsList));
    }
```

`list_black_text` looks like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- hidden color id-->
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/color_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

    <!--color name-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="15dip"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Question**

When I run the app the list seems to be populated by objects so I see it being populated with stuff like

```
com.my.package.Color@2343fa0
com.my.package.Color@2343fa0
...
```

What do I need to change so that I can see the name of the color in the list?

Note: I don't want to create a separate string array. I have tried that and it works. But I have additional requirement of being able to detect which `ID` color was clicked when the user clicks on a color name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is using the passed object's `toString` method for display.  So, if you want to display color names, just add a name variable, override the `toString` method and return the name of the color.

```
public class Color {
    private int id;
    private int name;
    private String strName;
    public String toString(){return this.strName;}
    //getter setter
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question with a note. I additionally want to be able to detect the `ID` of the color name that user would click. So, if i just overwrite the `toString` I wouldn't be able to do detect which `ID` user clicked on right..?

Comment: You can still get the ID.  The `ColorWrapper` object contains a `Color` object, which contains an ID.  When the user selects an item, get the ColorWrapper they selected, get the color object from the wrapper, then you can get your ID.

Comment: Ok.  This pattern is pretty frequent.  This kind of thing comes up so frequently I actually have a generic object I use.  I'll update my answer in case you want a more flexible object for this kind of thing.

Comment: That would be great! However, it bothers me that I have to iterate over a list of POJO that already has what I want but I still have to iterate just to populate my list with the strings.

Comment: Sweet! that works. Thanks. but how would I populate `color_id` (hidden) so that I can determine which list item the user clicked on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've gotten very little sleep the past few days. My previous answer was overcomplicated.  All you need to do is add a name variable to your `Color` object, and override its `toString` method.  My bad!

Comment: No worries and roger that. However, I'm still confused about how to populate `color_id` so that I can determine which color the user clicked on.

Comment: You don't need to populate color_id to determine which item was clicked.  The [adapter click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) gives you an index (called position in the listener) which you use with the colorsList you supply in your adapter.